# Placing member functions inside definition

Tags: c++, class, class-members

I'm in the process of moving a lot of oft-used functions into classes, and hit a snag that I can't explain.
With the "STD::random-device rd" and "std::mt19937 gen(rd())" declarations in global-space everything works fine.

```
include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

class randomGenerator
{
public:

    float getRandomFloat(float lowerLimit, float upperLimit)
    {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>dist(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        return (float)dist(gen);
    }
};
randomGenerator myGenerator;
```

But if I move the declarations into the class definition, the compiler complains...

```
include <random>

class randomGenerator
{
public:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    float getRandomFloat(float lowerLimit, float upperLimit)
    {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>dist(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        return (float)dist(gen);
    }
};
randomGenerator myGenerator;
```

`"E0757   member "randomGenerator::rd" is not a type name"`
and
`"E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::uniform_real_distribution<_Ty>::operator() [with _Ty=double]" matches the argument list"`

I've had similar trouble moving standalone variable declarations into other classes as well; seems almost hit-and-miss.
Is there some reason why this doesn't always work?  I can't see why some declarations (like above) will only work in global-space.

Comment: Why not create the distribution as `std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(lowerLimit, upperLimit);` and skip the cast in `return (float)dist(gen);`?

Answer (score 10):

For a quick fix, use brace initialization:

```cpp
class randomGenerator
{
public:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
    float getRandomFloat(float lowerLimit, float upperLimit)
    {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>dist(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        return (float)dist(gen);
    }
};
```

In your original definition, the compiler thinks `gen` is a member function returning a `std::mt19937` that takes another function returning an instance of type `rd`, which does not exist. This is commonly known as [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Also, as Ted Lyngmo mentioned down in the comments, if you only use the `std::random_device` to seed `gen` once, you can get rid of the member variable and use a temporary random device to construct `gen` directly:

```
class randomGenerator
{
public:
    std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    ...
};
```